# Xamarin forms open Instagram application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, instagram

How can I open Instagram application from my xamarin application?

I am using Device.OpenUri for Facebook and Twitter.

Is it possible to open Instagram by this way? please help me.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Comment: Try to open the instagram with URL Scheme provided by  nullpotent . If `Device.OpenUri` doesn't work, use `DependencyService`.

Comment: Following code worked!!

var uri = "instagram://user?username=user”;
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(uri));

Comment: can you please explain how you achieved this without using DI into native level?